# Getting the title and message of a notification in onResume in android

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to consume notifications in Android and have hit another hurdle.

In my manifest I have

```
<service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And in service.MyFirebaseMessagingService I have

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // handle the notification, snip
}
```

Everything is okay so far when the app is running - the notification is picked up by MyFirebaseMessagingService.

Issue #1
I want notifications to be handled on every activity - what I mean is I basically need a broadcast receiver on each activity. However, 95% of the activities will process the notification in the same way (store it in shared preferences) but 5% of the activities need to do something a little different. How to go about this?

Issue #2:
If the app is not open at the time when I receive a notification it goes into the sys tray, and when I click on it the start/launcher activity opens, but I want it to go to a different activity.

So I override the onResume in my start/launcher activity like so

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Bundle resumingBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(resumingBundle != null)
    {
        Log.d("DEBUG", resumingBundle.getString("message")); // error here
    }

}
```

The error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.werdna.apps.testreceivingnotifs/com.andrewb.testnotifapp.StartingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message.
```

How can I access the title and body of the notification from the intent?

Comment: For issue one: you can have all your activities extend a BaseActivity, which will contain the default message handling, and the edge case activities can override this behaviour

Comment: @howdoidothis I have tried that approach but the notifications are never received/handled by the base activity